# General applicability of the ～ませ conjugation

Tags: verbs, conjugations, honorifics

I have only found the ～ませ conjugation used in the following honorific verbs:

1. いらっしゃいませ
2. くださいませ
3. なさいませ

Can the conjugation be applied to other honorific verbs, like おっしゃいませ or めしあがりませ?

Or even common verbs, like がんばりませ or つづきませ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ませ` is the imperative form of the polite `ます`.

For all of your examples, you cannot directly add `ませ`, but you can add `くださいませ`:

> - おっしゃってくださいませ
> - 召し上がってくださいませ
> - 頑張ってくださいませ
> - 続いてくださいませ

or `なさいませ`:

> - おっしゃいなさいませ
> - 召し上がりなさいませ
> - 頑張りなさいませ
> - 続きなさいませ

Probably, only a few verbs including the ones Lukman mentions have the conjugation `ませ`.
And ento found that `召しませ`, is also possible.

My speculation for this is that only the verbs that:

1. have an auxiliary usage besides its main verb usage, and
2. are [suppletive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion) honorification

have the `ませ` conjugation.

> - いらっしゃる, いる 'be' [As main verb]
> - 召し上がって**いらっしゃる**, 食べて**いる** 'have been' [As auxiliary]
> - くださる, くれる 'give to me'　[As main verb]
> - 召し上がって**くださる**, 食べて**くれる** 'eat for me' [As auxiliary]
> - なさる, する 'do' [As main verb]
> - 召し上がり**なさる**, お食べに**なる** [As auxiliary]

Comment: So can you confirm that the conjugation is really restricted to the three verbs and all their compounds, and is not applicable for other verbs?

Comment: @Dave `ませ` attaches to `ください`, which selects the `て`-form. I removed that part from the answer.

Comment: There are 1M+ results for [召しませ](http://www.google.com/search?q=%2B%22%E5%8F%AC%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%22), a phrase I've heard from time to time but neglected to look up its exact meaning. Is this another exception?

Comment: @ento Thanks for pointing it out. I do not know much to be able to say anything about that.