# What conjugation/form is the ませ (for example: いらっしゃいませ)?

Tags: usage, verbs, conjugations

I know it's used for greetings in a restaurant or store. But what type of verb conjugation (ex: polite, plain, honorific, imperative, or something else) is it? Is it used with other verbs? Is it archaic Japanese or modern Japanese?

Comment: see also http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2097

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`~ませ` is the imperative form of the polite auxiliary verb `~ます` which connects to the conjunctive form of verbs. According to Daijirin it's used with the verbs `いらっしゃる`, `おっしゃる`, `くださる`, `なさる`, `申す` and `召す` etc (I've only seen `いらっしゃいませ`, `くださいませ` and `なさいませ` used myself though, so I'm not sure how common the other ones are).

It's used in modern Japanese, and I think it's frequently used with honorific language (though maybe not restricted to it as `申す` and `召す` are humble language). It's used to make requests/demands more polite as well as to add politeness to greetings as in `お帰りなさいませ`.

`いらっしゃいませ`/`くださいませ` etc are euphonic changes from the conjunctive forms `いらっしゃり`/`くださり` to `いらっしゃい`/`ください` (rather than being the imperative `いらっしゃい`/`ください`), together with the imperative polite `~ませ`.

---

(References: [Space ALC 日本語Q&A](http://home.alc.co.jp/db/owa/jpn_npa?stage=2&sn=102), [Dajirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&index=118441100000&pagenum=1), [Dajisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&index=17315400&pagenum=1))

Answer (score 4):

Just to supplement the others, here is the scheme of ます：

未然形 (Irrealis form) - ませ (ましよ)
連用形 (Continuative form) - まし
連体形 (Attributive form) - ます
已然形 / 仮定形 (Realis/Hypothetical form) - ますれ
命令形 (Imperative form) - ませ (まし)

Source: [Nihongoresources](http://grammar.nihongoresources.com/doku.php?id=conjugation#special_verbs%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)

And also from nihongoresources [further congujations of ます](http://grammar.nihongoresources.com/doku.php?id=conjugation#special_verbs%E3%81%BE%E3%81%991)

Comment: Not to be picky, but do you mind putting the english definition or example of what the kanji on the left side says?

Comment: @dotnetN00b I've been told that they're not significant in terms of modern analysis of Japanese grammar. But I'll add it in anyway.

Comment: @dotnetN00b 已然形 is only relevant in pre-modern Japanese. In modern Japanese it is 仮定形.

Answer (score 2):

It's polite imperative. It is derived from Edo-ben (as is all 丁寧語), but is still considered modern even though it isn't used outside 尊敬語 verbs.